# Run a java class without package structure

Tags: java

There is a class `a.b.c.Hello` of which I would just get the `Hello.class` file delivered. I would like to run using something like:

```
java Hello   

 //or

java a.b.c.Hello
```

This leads me to a `NoClassDefFoundError`. Normally I'd have the `a/b/c` dirs with the class insdie and I'd  add them to the `-classpath` option, but:

- Is there a way of running a class in a package like this **without having to put it inside `a/b/c`** to match the package name?

All solutions I've found state the directory structure has to match the package naming, but I'd like to run the `.class` file directly from the folder where it is  without recreating the folder structure

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way of running a class in a package like this without having to put it inside a/b/c to match the package name?

Yes: By using a jar. Put the `.class` file in the jar (with the correct path), and then:

```
java -cp TheJarFile.jar a.b.c.Hello
```

This is, of course, very much like putting it in an `a/b/c` directory; it's just that the directory is in the jar, not the file system.

Answer (score 0):

The packages do not just `structure` your classes (in folders), they also create a `namespace`. While the simple class name is Hello, the real class name is a.b.c.Hello.

That's because class names might repeat frequently (in different libs, f.e), but must be addressable on the other hand. For example: 'User', 'Logger', 'List', 'Date'.

Its not recommended, but you can put your class in the default package, too. Just remove the 'package ...' line.